# how to do I change the margins around a figure so it takes up maximum space

Tags: graphics, paper-size

I have a lot of graphs that I am trying to fit on one page to save trees. I have 66 graphs in total, I am thinking of putting 11 / page (I have 6 groups of 11 graphs) and double sided printing = 3 pages in total. So here is what I have:

[image]

My question is what can I do to either the paper style, graphic package or the graphs to expand this to the whole page.

Edit: My code. The "subfigure" block is repeated 8 more times to get a total of 11 diagrams like in the picture above.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]

\begin{subfigure}{.30\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{s1/graph_m6_c1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.30\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{s1/graph_m7_c1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.30\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{s1/graph_m8_c1.pdf}
\end{subfigure}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: With help of 'changepage' package? With it you can locally change text width.

Comment: Setting the graphs in a box and scaling it might work, but we'd have to see some code first.

Comment: I've edited my post with my all my code.

Comment: Have you thought about using `pdfpages` since your images are PDF? (Are they a standard size?)

Comment: They are not standard size. They are plots output from R.

Comment: So how can you use the same layout in each case? (They looked all the same size in your picture which is why I asked.) If the ratio of width:height varies, then they will not always fit neatly into the grid as in your picture.

Comment: Oh Yes, you are right. They are the same size that way. (I thought you meant if they are all A4 or Letter size)

Comment: You are already at .9\textwidth, which can easily be increased.  So do you want to reduce the left/right margins (using the geometry package) or change the aspect ratio (height=.25\textheight).

Comment: BTW, instead of subfigure you could use tabular or tabularx which would give you slightly more control.

Comment: Thanks @JohnKormylo, I am not sure how to use tabular. I'll try to google it. I'll try changing the aspect ratio. Is it possible to change the aspect ration on the entire figure?

Comment: The entire contents of the figure, but the figure environment has to contain whatever is to be displayed.  You will need to use \resizebox (also part of the graphicx package).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \includepdfmerge[
    nup=3x4,
    delta=5pt 30pt,
    width=.3\paperwidth,
    addtolist={
      1,figure,Graphs,graphs},
    pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}}% remove if you want empty pages; adjust if you want something fancier
    ]{
      pdf0,pdf1,pdf2,pdf3,pdf4,pdf5,pdf6,pdf7,pdf8,pdf9,pdf10,pdf1,{},
      pdf11,pdf12,pdf13,pdf14,pdf15,pdf16,pdf17,pdf18,pdf19,pdf20,pdf21,pdf1,{},
      pdf22}
\end{document}
```

[image: pages of graphs]

If you want separate entries for each group in the list of figures, try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\newcounter{graphgroup}
\setcounter{graphgroup}{1}
\includepdfset{
  nup=3x4,
  delta=5pt 30pt,
  addtolist={
    1,figure,Graph Group \thegraphgroup,graphgroup\thegraphgroup},
  pagecommand={\thispagestyle{plain}\refstepcounter{graphgroup}}% remove if you want empty pages; adjust if you want something fancier
}

\begin{document}
  \listoffigures
  \includepdfmerge[width=.3\paperwidth]{pdf0,pdf1,pdf2,pdf3,pdf4,pdf5,pdf6,pdf7,pdf8,pdf9,pdf10,pdf1,{}}
  \includepdfmerge[width=.3\paperwidth]{pdf11,pdf12,pdf13,pdf14,pdf15,pdf16,pdf17,pdf18,pdf19,pdf20,pdf21,pdf1,{}}
  \includepdfmerge[width=.3\paperwidth]{pdf22}
\end{document}
```

[image: pages of graphs as separate figures]

Comment: Thank you. I understand the code now too. I was in the process of converting pdfs to pngs so I can use Word or Publisher to just drag and drop, but this is nice. Saves me the management of 66 pngs!

Comment: Just a slight comment. My graphs are a little bit bigger, so I don't get the middle one on the last row. I guess maybe it dosnt want to cover the "page number"? edit: solved it by removing the empty `{}` "plot"

Comment: @masfenix It is hard to say but you can adjust the `width=.3\paperwidth` to reduce the size of each page slightly. (This option is just being passed to `graphicx`.) Or delete the `pagecommand` option if you don't want page numbers anyway. (I really included this just because your screenshot did but I wasn't sure what you meant by using the 'whole page'.) However, it would be weird for it to skip one to make room for the page number. What size are your graphs?

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did remove set the page style to `empty` to get rid of the page numbers. Everything works awesome now. Thanks, will accept as answer.

Comment: @masfenix You don't need to tell it `empty`. You can just delete that option since it uses `empty` by default. Glad it worked.

Answer (score 3):

In case you were still interested in the aspect ratio solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{mwe}% for images
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[p]%
\hfil\resizebox{.99\textwidth}{.99\textheight}{%
\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}ccc@{}}%
\includegraphics{example-image}&%
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&%
\includegraphics{example-image-b}\\[1ex]%
\includegraphics{example-image-c}&%
\includegraphics{example-image}&%
\includegraphics{example-image-a}\\[1ex]%
\includegraphics{example-image-b}&%
\includegraphics{example-image-c}&%
\includegraphics{example-image}\\[1ex]%
\includegraphics{example-image-a}&%
\includegraphics{example-image-b}%
\end{tabular}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: full page]

Comment: Thanks John. It seems like I will end up using your solution within my thesis. But right now cfr's solution is perfect for just analyzing my data.

Answer (score 3):

A `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox` package is another option to automatically compose figures (or boxes) over a page.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcbraster}[raster equal height, raster halign=center, blank, raster columns=3, graphics options={width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio}]
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-c}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-c}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-a}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-b}
  \tcbincludegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{tcbraster}

\end{document}
```

[image]